# JFrame Java setColor and fillRect staying Blank?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

Why am I getting a **Blank** screen instead of Black when I debug or run?? I've looked everywhere and tried a lot! Please help. I'm just trying to make my screen black as I am a beginner to all of this java coding. I don't believe anything is wrong with the code as I'm not getting any errors. I'm using eclipse.

```
package com.techon.rain;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static int width =300;
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
public static int scale =3;

private JFrame frame;
private Thread thread;
private boolean running = false;

public Game() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width*scale, height*scale);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    frame = new JFrame();
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Display");
    thread.start();
}
public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void run() {
    while(running);{
        update();
        render();
}
}
public void update() {

}

public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.frame.setResizable(false);
    game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
    game.frame.add(game);
    game.frame.pack();
    game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    game.frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
public void run() {
    while(running);{
        update();
        render();
}
```

by

```
public void run() {
    while(running){
        update();
        render();
}
```

due to while(running); it is not executing other stetement inside loop.

Comment: Yeah, the `render` method never was called with that error in while sentence!